# Specifying a relative path in Post-Deployment SQL files

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, project, sql-scripts

We have a post-deployment script in our `SQL Server` project which essentially performs a `bulk-insert` to populate tables after they're created. This is done by reading several `.csv` files:

```
BULK INSERT
    [dbo].[Table1]
    FROM '.\SubFolder\TestData\Data1.csv'
    WITH
    (
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    )

BULK INSERT
    [dbo].[Table2]
    FROM '.\SubFolder\TestData\Data2.csv'
    WITH
    (
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    )
```

The problem is Visual Studio is having a hard time finding the files:

```
Cannot bulk load because the file ".\SubFolder\TestData\Data1.csv" could not be opened. 
Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

The .csv files are checked in to the source control and I do see them when I go to the folder they're mapped to on my machine. I assume the problem is `.` isn't returning current path for the sql file being executed. Is there a way to get the relative path? Is there a macro (or a `SQLCMD Variable` maybe) that would give me current path of the file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the .csv files are in your VS project but the script will be executed on the SQL Server, so the files should be in a location that the server will have access to.  Maybe, you could add a Pre-Build event that will copy the .csv files to a shared drive on the server and then use a static path in your script that will take the files from the shared location.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old but still relevant. I found a working solution to this problem under the following conditions (what are optional because there are ways to overcome it) :

- You will use the "publish" option within the Visual studio IDE to deploy your app.
- The csv file is part of your project and configured to be copied to output folder.

Here are the steps:

1. Open Project Properties and go to SQLCMD Variables Section.
2. Add a new variable (for example $(CurrentPath))
3. In default Value put: $(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath)
4. Change your BULK code to:

```sql
BULK INSERT
    [dbo].[Table1]
    FROM '$(CurrentPath)\PathToFolderInsideOutputDirectory\Data1.csv'
    WITH
    (
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    )
```

5. Save all and compile.
6. Test your deploy using publish, ensure the $(CurrentPath) variable shows the right path(or press "Load values" button), press the publish button, all should work.

Comment: It's been a while but I currently have the same issue.  When set default to $(ProjectDir)$(OutputPath) the output path is wrong because it begins with a .(dot) which cause the path to be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a SSIS package and use `foreach Loop container` to loop through all the .csv files in a given path. See below the a demo configuration of `Foreach Loop Container`

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what the path is. The csv files are in source control and different users will have different paths based on the folder they've mapped the solution to.

Comment: Yea thats fine you can use a variable for directory path, which will be populated at runtime. Any user who executes the package will provide the path at run time before executing the package.

Comment: I'm trying to see if there's a way VS can locate the file itself without having to ask the user to specify the path...

Comment: How can you expect sql server to know the path :)

Comment: That's exactly why I asked if there's a macro or something :)